# Usage: Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, terminology

This isn't a math question, but rather a question is word usage in mathematics.

Why do people say " $f$ is  an isomorphism," or "$f$ is a diffeomorphism," but in complex analysis, we say that "$f$ is a holomorphic function?  What's wrong with "$f$ is a holomorphism?"

i.e. why are holomorphic functions called "holomorphic functions" and not "holomorphisms?"

Comment: Being holomorphic is a property of a function that has a fixed codomain (usually the complex numbers), while homomorphisms are between “variable” domains and codomains.

Comment: I've heard "biholomorphism" used, although not really "holomorphism".